# How to get a spring bean in a bean-defining method

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I have a java config where ServiceB depends on ServiceA:

```
@Bean
ServiceA getServiceA() { return new ServiceA(); }
@Bean
ServiceB getServiceB() { return new ServiceB(getServiceA()); }
```

Then I want to declare ServiceA (but no ServiceB) as a component. I add `@ScanPackage` to config and annotate ServiceA:

```
@Component
class ServiceA { .. }
```

How to declare method `getServiceB()` now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Rohan already wrote in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42132301/4969410), Spring's `@Bean` annotation can inject dependencies of other Spring beans, in the same manner as constructor-based dependency injection does.

I would just add that there are also other possibilities to do dependency injection, when defining a bean in java config. `@Configuration` annotated class is a Spring bean as any other Spring bean, so you can auto-wire a dependency, as is usually done in Spring and then use this dependency when defining your `@Bean`, like:

```
@Autowired
private ServiceA serviceA;

@Bean
public ServiceB getServiceB() {
    return new ServiceB(serviceA);
}
```

Since Spring Framework 4.3, you are also able to do constructor injection in `@Configuration` classes - which is yet another way to inject dependencies.

See more details in [spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java-injecting-imported-beans).

Comment: Quick correction: I wrote the answer you have linked to, but am not the OP as your answer sees to assume :)

Comment: @RohanPrabhu, you're right. :) You've edited the question and I was not careful enough to notice that you're not the OP. I've corrected my answer and upvote yours.

Answer (score 3):

Spring auto-injects method parameters by type for Bean defining methods:

```
@Bean
ServiceB getServiceB(ServiceA serviceA) {
    return new ServiceB(serviceA);
}
```

Now you don't have to worry about how `ServiceA` is provided.

Comment: What if `ServiceB` is used by `ServiceC` and `ServiceD` and so on? Shall I add parameter `ServiceA serviceA` to all method declarations?

Comment: Once `ServiceB` is defined as a bean, you can just use that in a method parameter. `@Bean ServiceC getServiceC(ServiceB serviceB) { new ServiceC(serviceB); }`. This also is the right way to do it because you would be using the same instance of the bean (unless you are using a prototype scope), and also not duplicating the code for the creation of `ServiceB`